# how to fetch values in jquery which is actually set by PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I am working on project which is basically based on HTML and PHP. I set element's attribute value using PHP.

```
<div id='<?php echo $Id;?>'></div>
```

Now i want to fetch that same id on jQuery but it stated me error with function is undefined.

```
$('#<?php echo $Id; ?>').remove();
```

error is

> remove() is undefined.

please help me.

Comment: can you paste more of the javascript and html/php?

Comment: Your code does not appear as such in your message. Also, your PHP code was truncated. Use the "code" tag to properly highlight it

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: yes.i included jquery on top of the page

Comment: for php page:<code><div id='<?php echo $Id;?>'></div>  </code> and for jquery part <code>$('#<?php echo $Id; ?>').remove();</code>.so this is my code.help me please.

Comment: Edit your question and include all the html.

Comment: HTML Part: <div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="<?php echo $Id;?>" title="<?php echo $modelno;?>"
    execute="getModify();">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="xxx" id="xxx" action="" method="post">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="#666666" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">
  <tr>                                       PHP PArt:---------------------------------------$.get('proceedcart1.php',{task:task,item:item,qty:q},
     function(data) {
   
      dijit.byId('<?php echo $Id;?>').remove();
      });

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: `.remove()` is undefined because you have not loaded jQuery properly into your project or because your script is at the top of the page prior to loading jQuery or because your script is at the top of the page and you have not put your code into a document ready handler. Without seeing more of your markup it would be impossible for anyone to guess.

Comment: In addition, your use of PHP echo in the jQuery selector *will not work* the way you think it will.

Comment: yeah i agree with that but i can not show full code infront of you that's why i used snippets and i loaded properly which is same as Jquery w3school standard.

Comment: why you guys give negative reviews to someone's post?just help us.nobody is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Id = 666;
<div id="<?php echo $Id;?>"></div> 
$("<?php echo '#' . $Id; ?>").remove();
```

with ' the div's ID don't work + JS is better view, nice fit

Comment: it is string with numbers so is it safe to use parse?

Comment: I edit a little, the parse nvm! It's not required. ;)

Comment: It shows my last row result.so it is working.Thank you phil.i appreciate that.

Comment: Glad i could help :) Ty for letting know :)

Answer (score 0):

In `HTML`, `ID` tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: True, but what does this have to do with the OP's question? HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the id attribute. The only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters.

Comment: it is starting with number.is that the issue what you think?

Comment: All browsers support ID start with a number (HTML5)

Comment: But my question is that is it safe against mysql injection?